# The kernel of an element of End(End(V)) for V a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am a grad student currently studying for an upcoming algebra qualifying exam. I have been working through previous exams and I have gotten through most of them, but I am stuck on this question:

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $F$. If $A$ is an endomorphism of $V$, then $A$ induces an endomorphism $\Phi_A$ on the vector space of all endomorphisms of $V$ by sending an endomorphism $B$ to $AB$. What possible dimensions can $\ker\Phi_A$ attain?

So, thus far I have been able to show that $0\leq \dim(\ker\Phi_A)\leq n^2$and that for all $0\leq l\leq n$, there exists $A\in End(V)$ such that $\dim(\ker\Phi_A)=ln$. Looking at examples I would guess these are the only realizable dimensions, but I cannot figure out a proof of this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hint: $B\in \operatorname{Ker}\Phi_A$ if and only if $\operatorname{Img}B\subset \operatorname{Ker}A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, as the hint says, $AB=0$ means that the image of $B$ is contained in the kernel $\ker A$ of$~A$, one has a natural isomorphism between $\ker\Phi_A$ and $L(V,\ker A)$, the space of linear maps $B:V\to\ker A$. The fact that $n$ divides $\dim\ker\Phi_A$ now follows from $\dim L(V,\ker A)=(\dim V)(\dim\ker A)$.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ acting on End($V$) is the char.poly of $A$, raised to the exponent $n$.  The answer is therefore "multiples of $n$ between $0$ and $n^2$" as proposed in the question.